# Delphi 5 Installation Error

Tags: delphi

I am trying installing Delphi 5 on my computer. As soon as the installation starts I get:

> Error copying File

followed by:

> Setup has detected a -113 error while attempting to copy files.   This 
>   indicates that setup could not find a file in the "RunImage" directory.

Now the setup file does includes "RunImage" directory. The File is located in the D drive on another computer which I have mapped to my computer as Drive Z and I am running it from the Mapped Drive Z.

I searched online for this Error. Some recommend that if I am installing from a network location then the location has to mapped to my computer as a Driver with a name to solve the issue. I did map the location but still getting the same error.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  If it's win10 you've probably not got the drive mapped in an elevated context.

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem and i solved it by this method:

After unpacking the archive(the delphi5 zip file that you downloaded), make the root directory with the command Subst X: "path to installer". Run the standard Borland installer, the Install.exe program, there.

Answer (score 0):

As J.. already suggested in his comment: Windows >= Vista automatically runs programs containing the string "setup" in the name in elevated mode. In that mode, you don't have the same mapped drives as in your normal user mode. So, the program starts (which is actually inconsistent with security model, because in elevated mode, the executable itself should not be available) and then cannot find any additional files because the drive mapping does not exist.

Solution: Copy the whole installation directory to a local drive. You can delete it after the installation has finished.

Note: While I think this will solve that particular problem, it does not mean, that the rest of the installation will work.